# Codeigniter Ion_auth sends a second email on user activate

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ion-auth

I use the `Ion_Auth` in my Codeigniter Project and I would like to send a second Email after the user has been activating the account and I was taking a look on the code and actually what I'm trying is:

In my controller

```
$activation = $this->ion_auth->activate($id, $code, $reciver);
```

Than in `Ion_auth_model->activate()`

I would like to send another email to activated user but I do not really know how should be done

What I done and seems to work but if there is better approach which doesn't use such a lot code as above, would be welcome

```
//activate the user
public function activate($id, $code = false) {
    if ($code !== false) {

        $btc_reciver = $this->bitcoin->getnewaddress();
        $this->load->model('ion_auth_model');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $user = $this->ion_auth_model->user($id)->row();
        $identity = $this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth');
        $activation = $this->ion_auth->activate($id, $code, $btc_reciver);
        $data = array(
            'btc_send_address' => $btc_reciver,
            'identity' => $user->{$identity},
            'username' => $user->username,
            'id' => $user->id,
            'email' => $user->email,
        );
        $message = $this->load->view($this->config->item('email_templates', 'ion_auth') . $this->config->item('email_account_confirmation', 'ion_auth'), $data, true);
        $this->email->clear();
        $this->email->from($this->config->item('admin_email', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth'));
        $this->email->to($user->email);
        $this->email->subject($this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth') . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('email_activation_subject'));
        $this->email->message($message);


        if ($this->email->send() == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect("login", 'refresh');
        }

    } else if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
        $activation = $this->ion_auth->activate($id);
    }

    if ($activation) {
        //redirect them to the auth page
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
        redirect("login", 'refresh');
    } else {
        //redirect them to the forgot password page
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
        redirect("forgot_password", 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a hook to the "post_activate_successful" trigger to send the email.  Here is an article explaining how to use hooks:

http://www.codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/01/using-hooks-with-ion_auth

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. Congrats for this nice Library